# How to use TVirtualStringTree to display multi-line items and "expanded" select item?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I'm looking to create a look similar to the image below (which I know was done using TVirtualStringTree), but I haven't found any example code on how to accomplish this.

Anyone knows how I can have multi-line items like on the example below, and "expand" the select item to show more lines?

[image]

Comment: Image not available anymore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please take a look at VT Demos\Advenced. In there you have a Multiline nodes demo which I guess might be the thing you are looking for.

Demos can be found [here](http://www.soft-gems.net/supplement/download.php?ID=33)

**Edit:**  The download page is [here](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/all-downloads) and the third item is the demos.

Comment: I personally don't like when a link tries to download something directly, especially when the URL is not explicit about the content. I added the download page link as a more candid reference.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you've got an answer, but I'll give you a couple hints for putting this into practice because it's been a little wonky for me. (At least in Delphi 7)

1. If you do a #13#10 for a new line make sure you've got a space after the the #10, otherwise you will not get a line break.
2. VirtualTree.MultiLine[node] := true will allow multi line, but not necessarily make it multiline.
3. Do VirtualTree.InvalidateNode(Node) then VirtualTree.Refresh the tree to get the new size for the node after you've changed the caption.